# angular5 model-driven invalid form

Tags: angular, forms, validation, updates, reactive

I'm currently trying to build a model driven form with validators.
In that form, I pass values from the model I get back from an API.

Problem is : even if I define the "value" directiv for my input fields, the form is always invalid.

I don't understand why because the values I get from the model match my validators...

html code :

```
<form (ngSubmit)="addOrUpdate()" [formGroup]="policyForm" class="form">

        <div class="containerLeft">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput name="noPoliceInterne" id="noPoliceInterne" formControlName="numeroPoliceInterne"
            placeholder="numeroPoliceInterne"
            value="{{policy.numeroPoliceInterne}}" required />
          </mat-form-field>
          <br>

          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput name="nomClient" id="nomClient" formControlName="nomClient"
            placeholder="Client"
            value="{{policy.nomClient}}" required />
          </mat-form-field>
          <br>

          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput name="mtPrimeNetteAnnuelle" id="mtPrimeNetteAnnuelle" formControlName="montantPrimeNetteAnnuelle"
            placeholder="Prime nette annuelle "
            value="{{policy.montantPrimeNetteAnnuelle | currency}}" required />
          </mat-form-field>
          <br>
     </div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button mat-raised-button type="button" [routerLink]="['/policies']">Back</button>
          <button mat-raised-button *ngIf="policy.numeroPoliceInterne > 0" type="submit" color="primary" [disabled]="policyForm.invalid">Update</button>
          <button mat-raised-button *ngIf="policy.numeroPoliceInterne == 0" type="submit" color="primary" [disabled]="policyForm.invalid">Add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

component code :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.createFormControls();
    this.createForm();
  }

  createFormControls() {
    this.numeroPoliceInterne = new FormControl(this.numeroPoliceInterne, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]);
    this.noPoliceEtOrdre = new FormControl(this.noPoliceEtOrdre, Validators.required);
    this.noCompte = new FormControl(this.noCompte, Validators.required);
    this.noCompagnie = new FormControl(this.noCompagnie, Validators.required);
    this.nomClient = new FormControl(this.nomClient, Validators.required);
    this.montantPrimeNetteAnnuelle = new FormControl(this.montantPrimeNetteAnnuelle, Validators.required);
    this.montantPrimeTTCAnnuelle = new FormControl(this.montantPrimeTTCAnnuelle, Validators.required);
    this.dateEffetPolice = new FormControl(this.dateEffetPolice);
  }


  createForm() {

    this.policyForm = this.fb.group({

      numeroPoliceInterne: this.numeroPoliceInterne,
      noPoliceEtOrdre: this.noPoliceEtOrdre,
      noCompte: this.noCompte,
      noCompagnie: this.noCompagnie,
      nomClient: this.nomClient,
      montantPrimeNetteAnnuelle: this.montantPrimeNetteAnnuelle,
      montantPrimeTTCAnnuelle: this.montantPrimeTTCAnnuelle,
      dateEffetPolice: this.dateEffetPolice,

    });
  }
```

Did i missed something...?
regards,
j0w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reactive (model-driven) forms, it does not recognize values set with the `value` attribute. Rather, you need to use `setvalue` or `patchValue` to set defaults.

```
this.productForm.patchValue({
  productName: this.product.productName,
  productCode: this.product.productCode,
  starRating: this.product.starRating,
  description: this.product.description
});
```

You can find a complete working example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms/tree/master/APM-Updated

Comment: thank you you your answer, the patchValue method seems to work fine! And thank you for providing the example, it helped a lot understanding the way to create a reactive model-driven form! :)

Comment: there's is just one thing i don't understand : the display message for validators error. by following your example, it only display the "field is required" error, the others are not displayed with this : 
      `<mat-form-field>
        <input matInput name="noPoliceInterne" id="noPoliceInterne" formControlName="numeroPoliceInterne"
        placeholder="numeroPoliceInterne" required
        [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': displayMessage.numeroPoliceInterne }"/>
        <div class="errorMsg">
            {{ displayMessage.numeroPoliceInterne }}
        </div>
      </mat-form-field>`

Comment: I'm not clear on the question. Could you create a new question about this and expand on it?

Comment: oops, sorry for the long time : i found the error i made so, it's all fine now. thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use formBuilder instead in your component, it's an Angular service from ReactiveFormModule, to create your formControls and formGroup, than initialize your form with setValue (all values once)! (your html it's right)!

Comment: I already use FormBuilder. I did not knew the setValue and patchValue methods tho... thanks ! :)